# Python Numpy nan_to_num help

Tags: python, function, numpy

I'm having some trouble with Numpy's nan_to_num function: I've got an array where the last column contains fewer elements than the other columns, and when I import it into Python, it places 'nan's to fill out the array. That's just fine until I need to do some other things that get tripped-up by the 'nan's.

I'm trying to use 'nan_to_num' with no success. It's likely a small thing I'm missing, but I can't figure it out.

Here's some simple input and output:

input:

```
a = numpy.array([[1, nan, 3]])
print a
numpy.nan_to_num(a)
print a
```

output

```
[[  1.  nan   3.]]
[[  1.  nan   3.]]
```

The second 'nan' should be a zero...
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't changed the value of `a`. Try this:

```
a = numpy.array([[1, nan, 3]])
a = numpy.nan_to_num(a)
print a
```